# gitlab, how to "unpublish" gitlab pages site using cli

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

**Project:**

Terminal: Win10, Powershell Core

Static html project,private repo, published from "public" folder using gitlab ci with yml:

```
image: busybox

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo 'Nothing to do...'
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
    expire_in: 1 day
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

**TODO: stop/pause site using cli**

I can pause site using gitlab web interface (project/deploy/pages/remove pages). And then restart site by re-running ci with command:

```
glab pipeline run
```

But I have no way to do this using cli.

I have tried to call api:

```
curl --request 'DELETE' --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <project-token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/pages"
```

but constantly get 403 forbidden error. Is there a simpler way to stop pages site , using glab cli ? glab is authenticated using personal access token (commands like repo create, pipeline run etc works ok)